# Can't login to pgadmin4

Tags: database

I've successfully installed `postgres` and `pgadmin4`.

When I try to access pgadmin4 in the browser I'm being asked to login in with an email and password.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could (re)move `/var/lib/pgadmin`.
Restart your pgAdmin4 in the shell again.

You will now have the possibility to set email and password:

NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.

Enter the email address and password to use for the initial pgAdmin user account:

This was my way.